# How to change css if a specific string is in the URL?

Tags: html, css

For an example, if I were to have a URL `https://example.com/search.php?q=foobar&type=0&p=0`, and I wanted to target specifically URLs with "type=0" in it, how would I do that?

I know you can use `@document url()` for URLs who's full name is known, but not with the link above.

EDIT: I'm not looking for the href value, I'm looking for something that will get the current pages URL, and check if it has a particular string in it.
For example, if I were at the URL `https://example.com/search.php?q=foobar&type=0&p=0`, it would change whatever element I tell it to, but if it's `https://example.com/search.php?q=foobar&type=1&p=0`, it doesn't.

I probably should have made that a bit clearer.

Comment: @ecjwthx I am not sure that your edit makes it totally clear what you want to do. Do you want to target the element and change its CSS based on "type=0", for example,  or do you also want to get the URL and do something with that as well?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the an [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) for this:

```css
[href*="type=0"] {
  color: green;
}

[href*="zanzabar"] {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://example.com/search.php?q=foobar&type=0&p=0">Link with type=0</a>
<a href="https://example.com/search.php?q=foobar&p=0">Link without</a>


<h2>Edit searching for just the parameter string without value</h2>
<a href="https://example.com/search.php?q=foobar&zanzabar=0&p=0">Link with type=0</a>
<a href="https://example.com/search.php?q=foobar&zanzabar=1&p=0">Link without</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Read the url parameters and find the one you are looking for

```js
const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
const pageType = urlParams.get('type');
console.log(pageType);
```